# How do I reference the checkbox of the userform with a variable

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

Could anyone tell me how to reference a checkbox of the userform with a variable?

For example I have something like these,

```
   if UserForm1.checkbox1.Value
   if UserForm1.checkbox2.Value 
   if UserForm1.checkbox3.Value
```

I have to check nearly 40 to 50 checkboxes. But writing the 40 to 50 statements like these is time consuming and also makes a bigger code.

So I was kinda thinking to loop through them:

```
 For i = 1 To 50 
   UserForm1.checkbox & i .Value
 Next i
```

Something like that. I didn't find too much but I found it at the end. This is the link http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43358 and the answer was like these,

```
UserForm1.Shapes("Checkbox" & i).Value
```

But it isn't working. Does any one know the way to do it? Is it possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & i).Value
```