# Checking one box unchecks the adjacent box in Excel

Tags: excel

I am currently trying work on a code that can loop through all the check boxes and uncheck a box if the box next to it is checked.

Currently, I have something written out, and I know it's no where near what I need it to be. I know how to do it individually by box:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
       CheckBox2.Value = False
   End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
 If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1.Value = False
 End If
End Sub
```

However, I have several hundred lines of check boxes that I'd have to write this for so if I could just loop through the check boxes it would be a life saver!So I started out with:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
a = 2
If CheckBoxi.Value = True Then
    CheckBoxa.Value = False
End If
If CheckBoxa.Value = True Then
    CheckBoxi.Value = False
End If
i = i + 2
a = a + 2
End
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The behavior you're trying to achieve is handled by 'radio buttons', not check boxes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966611/how-do-i-reference-the-checkbox-of-the-userform-with-a-variable

Comment: Both these comments above make sense. What do you wish to achieve here? Radio button behavior or actual Checkboxes in a list with a Checkbox next to it that might have been checked? And are you working on a userform or worksheet?

Comment: It does sound like you should use radio buttons. Is there a reason for check boxes? You will need to give examples of how they are named, and with that many check boxes you will also need to verify named check boxes are in their correct positions. What do you want to happen if both check boxes are ticked? Do you want it to default to a certain check box? if so which?

Comment: The purpose is to switch between either "order needed" or "order placed" on an inventory checklist but if I don't need to order then nothing needs to be checked, which is the problem with radio buttons. I want to have the option to have both boxes in a row unchecked, and also if one is checked then the other is unchecked, if that makes sense. So far every odd numbered checkbox is under the order needed tab and every even numbered checkbox is under the order placed tab.

Comment: Still trying to work out your requirements... If no boxes are checked, then do nothing... If 'Order Needed' (Odd) is checked and 'Order Placed' (Even) is unchecked, then do nothing... If  'Order Placed' is checked and 'Order Needed' is unchecked, then do nothing... If 'Order Needed' and 'Order Placed' are both checked then uncheck 'Order Needed'... Can you confirm this or exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I mean. Once the order is placed, it can uncheck order needed as the order has already been placed. Then upon receipt I can go back to having nothing selected. With radio buttons if I understand correctly, I can only ever have one or the other unchecked, but not both.

Comment: In your case, I would go with 3 radio buttons first one labelled something like 'Not Required' (or something more relevant for your requirements) then the other two:  'Order Needed'  'Order Placed'.  This would solve the issue for using vba to control the check boxes conditions. It should be possible to create these sets of radio buttons using VBA this would then save a lot of work creating them manually. Are your check boxes linked to/or have an affect on any cellswithin your workbook?

Comment: Well I plan on adding a button that links to the catalog of the item needing purchasing, and if said button is clicked it automatically switches to "Order Placed", however, I could achieve this with radio buttons as well right?